# Looping checkbox Coldfusion

Tags: list, coldfusion, cfloop

I have a loop with checkbox values.

```
<cfloop list="form.check_values" index="i" delimiters=",">
</cfloop>
```

The problem is, when i loop the list results something like:

[image]

How can i loop that list to result something like query loop:

[image]

Comment: How have you tried to solve this problem? Let's see some code.

Comment: Your second cfdump is a query. Too me it looks like the results of a `select in`

Perhaps you could query your DB?

Comment: list="form.check_values" should be list="#form.check_values#"

Comment: Yes, the second dump is a query but i don´t know if that list could shown like query result because i have to code some queries value by value

Comment: Hint number 1 - you don't need a loop.  Hint number 2 - `cfqueryparam` has a list attribute,

Comment: What do you mean by "have to code some queries value by value"? What have you tried so far? What was the result and what did you expect it to be instead?

Comment: Better yet, what exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Using a loop and a delim form field to build down-stream queries seems like it's a) going to beat up your database when one query might work, and b) just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you want is

```
<cfquery name="result">
    SELECT idEstado, nombreEstado
    FROM   sometable
    WHERE  idEstando IN (<cfquery cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#form.check_values#" list="true">)
    ORDER BY idEstado
</cfquery>
```